# Only update UI when there are changes in the server, using streambuilder

Tags: flutter, stream-builder

I am using streambuilder to check whether a new order is placed  or not.
I am checking the order status, if the order status is unknown I want to show a pop up, which works fine. but if i don't select an option to update the order status, streambuilder refreshes after a few seconds, and show another pop up on top of it.

Get Orders Function:

```
Future<Orders> getOrders() async {
    String bsid = widget.bsid;
    try {
      Map<String, dynamic> body = {
        "bsid": bsid,
      };
      http.Response response = await http.post(
          Uri.parse(
              "**API HERE**"),
          body: body);

      Map<String, dynamic> mapData = json.decode(response.body);

      Orders myOrders;
      print(response.body);

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print("Success");
        myOrders = Orders.fromJson(mapData);
      }

      return myOrders;
    } catch (e) {}
  }
```

Here's the stream function:

```
 Stream<Orders> getOrdersStrem(Duration refreshTime) async* {
while (true) {
  await Future.delayed(refreshTime);
  yield await getOrders();
}}
```

StreamBuilder:

```
StreamBuilder<Orders>(
            stream: getOrdersStrem(
              Duration(
                seconds: 2,
              ),
             
            ),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Center(
                     CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive(),
                );
              }
              var orders = snapshot.data.statedatas;

              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: orders.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  var orderResponse =
                      snapshot.data.statedatas[index].strAccept;
                  print(orderResponse);

                  if (orderResponse == "0") {
                    print("order status unknown");

                    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
                      _playFile();
                      showCupertinoDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
                          title: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              "#${orders[index].ordrAutoid}",
                            ),
                          ),
                          content: Row(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 120,
                                child: ElevatedButton(
                                  style: ButtonStyle(
                                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty
                                        .resolveWith<Color>(
                                      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                                        if (states.contains(
                                            MaterialState.pressed))
                                          return Colors.black;
                                        return Colors
                                            .green; // Use the component's default.
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    _stopFile();
                                    Navigator.pop(context);
                                    await changeOrderStatus(
                                        orders[index].orid, "accept");

                                    // setState(() {});
                                  },
                                  child: Text('Accept'),
                                ),
                              ),

                              SizedBox(
                                width: 15,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 120,
                                child: ElevatedButton(
                                  style: ButtonStyle(
                                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty
                                        .resolveWith<Color>(
                                      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                                        if (states.contains(
                                            MaterialState.pressed))
                                          return Colors.black;
                                        return Colors
                                            .red; // Use the component's default.
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    _stopFile();
                                    Navigator.pop(context);
                                    await changeOrderStatus(
                                        orders[index].orid, "Reject");

                                    // setState(() {});
                                  },
                                  child: Text('Reject'),
                                ),
                              ),
                              // TextButton(
                              //   onPressed: () async {
                              //     _stopFile();
                              //     Navigator.pop(context);
                              //     await changeOrderStatus(
                              //         orders[index].orid, "reject");
                              //   },
                              //   child: Text('reject'),
                              // ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }).then((value) {
                      _stopFile();
                      print("ENDING");
                    });
                  }
return Container();
```

Comment: Please post your 'getOrders()` function.

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad I have edited getOrders() function in the question. Have a look

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable to check for the last known order status, outside your if statement, and when a new value comes, compare it to the old value first, then do the if statement logic.

```
//This is outside the stream builder:
String orderResponseCheck = "";
.
.
.
//This is inside your streambuidler, if the orderResponseCheck is still equal to "", the if statement will be executed,
//and the value of orderResponse wil be assigned to it. This will only show the alert dialog if the orderResponse status changes from the one that previously triggered it.

 var orderResponse =snapshot.data.statedatas[index].strAccept;
 print(orderResponse);
 if (orderResponseCheck != orderResponse && orderResponse == "0") {
 orderResponseCheck = orderResponse;
.
.
.
//logic same as before
```

Comment: thanks Huthaifa, you people are truly a life saver.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call `showCupertinoDialog` (and probably `_playFile()`) from your `build` method. Wrapping it with `Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () { ... })` was probably a workaround for an error that was given by the framework.

The `build` method can get executed multiple times. You probably want a way to run `_playFile` and show the dialog that isn't depending on the UI. I don't think `StreamBuilder` is the right solution for this.

You could use a `StatefulWidget` and execute `listen` on a stream from the `initState` method. `initState` will only be called once.

Comment: I guess this looks like a more legit answer to follow, but seems like i have to do a lot of work around my code. But still I will look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From what I'm reading, you're querying your API every two seconds.
Every time your API answers, you're pushing the new datas to your StreamBuilder, which explains why you're having multiple pop-ups are stacking.

One simple solution to your problem would be to have a boolean set to true when the dialog is displayed to avoid showing it multiple times.

```
bool isDialogShowing = false;
...
if (orderResponse == "0" && !isDialogShowing) {
  isDialogShowing = true;
...
```

But there are a few mistakes in your code that you should avoid like :

- Infinite loops
- Querying your API multiple times automatically (it could DDOS your service if plenty of users are using your app at the same time)
- Showing your Dialog in a ListView builder

Comment: Thanks mate, this work like a charm
And thanks for pointing out the mistakes too. I will look into it...